# Compare files including final newline

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've made three text files: `0nl.txt`, `1nl.txt` and `2nl.txt`.

They both have the same content:

```
test
hello
```

The only difference between them is how many newlines they have after the final 'o', with 0, 1 and 2 respectively.

I can compare between the files using `FC`:

```
C:\Users\NeatN\Desktop\fctest>fc 0nl.txt 1nl.txt
Comparing files 0nl.txt and 1NL.TXT
FC: no differences encountered


C:\Users\NeatN\Desktop\fctest>fc 0nl.txt 2nl.txt
Comparing files 0nl.txt and 2NL.TXT
***** 0nl.txt
***** 2NL.TXT

*****


C:\Users\NeatN\Desktop\fctest>fc 1nl.txt 2nl.txt
Comparing files 1nl.txt and 2NL.TXT
***** 1nl.txt
***** 2NL.TXT

*****
```

`COMP`, on the other hand, detects that they have different sizes but doesn't show the differences between them:

```
C:\Users\NeatN\Desktop\fctest>comp 0nl.txt 1nl.txt /M
Comparing 0nl.txt and 1nl.txt...
Files are different sizes.


C:\Users\NeatN\Desktop\fctest>comp 0nl.txt 2nl.txt /M
Comparing 0nl.txt and 2nl.txt...
Files are different sizes.


C:\Users\NeatN\Desktop\fctest>comp 1nl.txt 2nl.txt /M
Comparing 1nl.txt and 2nl.txt...
Files are different sizes.
```

**How do I detect the missing newline in `0nl.txt` compared to `1nl.txt`, and show it to the user?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FC /B 0nl.txt 1nl.txt > NUL
IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (ECHO TEST PASSED) ELSE (
    ECHO TEST FAILED - output doesn't match
    FC /N 0nl.txt 1nl.txt
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 ECHO There is a missing or extra newline character ^(\n^) at the end of the file
)
```

Essentially, I do a binary comparison first, and if that fails then there must be a difference. If an ASCII comparison passes later, then the difference must be in the final newline.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `fc /n`. The `/n` parameter is
[described](https://ss64.com/nt/fc.html) as :

```
/N    Display line numbers during an ASCII comparison.
```

This would look on comparison like this :

[image]

Comment: This doesn't do what I need: FC still ignores the missing newline in 0nl.txt.

Comment: Is the problem that the newlines are Linux type line-feeds rather than Windows type carriage-return/line-feeds? Could you post these two files?

Comment: No, they were all made with notepad. I managed to figure it out, see my own answer - maybe that will clarify what I meant.